# Oracle: Recreate database view after modifying varchar column size

Tags: oracle

I've made some changes to columns in a database table (increasing the size of varchar), however I need to have the view of the table refreshed to pick up this change. In SQL server 2005 I would use the script to -> alter to recreate the script for the view. I'm trying to figure out what the Oracle SQL command would be to rebuild the view to display the change of the column?

Answer (score 7):

Unless your view is explicitly restricting the size of the column, it will pick up the change automatically. It may have been invalidated by the table change but would be automatically recompiled when first used; or can be manually recompiled with `alter view <view name> compile`.

Comment: hi. Is there any way to check what change caused the view to become invalid?

Comment: @sonic - not that I'm aware of off-hand, though there may well be something in the data dictionary if you can dig deep enough. You can certainly see the dependencies to get an idea whether a change might invalidate anything. You should ask this as a new question, probably on [dba.se].

Comment: thank you Alex. Ya i have the query which shows all the dependacies. But there are lots of dependacies and its difficult to find which one made the object invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you do so:

```
create table sample_table(text varchar2(10));
insert into sample_table (text) values('text...');
create view sample_view as select * from sample_table;
select * from sample_view;
alter table sample_table modify text varchar2(200);
```

You do not do anything to promote this change in view in Oracle database.

Or you can use "ALTER VIEW sample_view COMPILE" (how wrote @AlexPole or @devio). Oracle do this automatically when you firstly use select on sample_view after alter table.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ALTER VIEW MyView COMPILE;
```